# Помогите скруглить кнопку

Tags: html, css

Сразу обозначу проблему. Имеется Header, в котором находится поисковая строка. В поисковой строке есть небольшая иконка в блоке search-box, которая скругляется с помощью border-radius. Но по какой-то причине она не хочет становится круглой при значении 50%. Помогите разобраться
Имеется такой HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/main.css">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <script defer src="http://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="header">
                <a class="logo" href="./index.html"> <img src="img/image.png" width="70"/></a>
                <div class="search-box">
                    <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="" placeholder="Type to search">
                    <a class="search-btn" href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="header-right">
                  <a class="active" href="#home">Главная</a>
                  <a href="#contact">Контакты</a>
                  <a href="#about">О нас</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <main class="main">
            
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

И такой CSS:

```
.header {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 20px 10px;
  }
  
  /* Стиль ссылок шапки */
  .header a {
    float: left;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    
  }

.search-box{
    position: absolute;
    left: 500px;
    height: 40px;
    
    border-radius: 40px;
    background: #2f3640;
    padding: 10px;
}
.search-box:hover > .search-txt{
    width: 240px;
    padding: 0 6px;
}
.search-box:hover > .search-btn{
    background: white;
    
}
.search-btn{
    color: white;
    float: right;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #2f3640;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.search-txt{
    border: none;
    background : none;
    outline: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 0px;
}
```

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` должен быть самой первой строкой...

Comment: @ksa К сожалению, это не причина

Comment: Тебе конечно видней... :) Но я решил отредактировать твой вопрос и поместить его в здешнюю "песочницу" - все там закругляется. Я просто убрал твое "подключение" стилей в первой строке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В поисковой строке есть небольшая иконка в блоке search-box, которая скругляется с помощью border-radius. Но по какой-то причине она не хочет становится круглой при значении 50%.

Всему "виной" вот этот селектор

```
.header a {}
```

Он имеет больший приоритет в сравнении с

```
.search-btn {}
```

Если его "усилить" - см. мой пример - ссылка будет закругляться.

```css
.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: none;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}


/* Стиль ссылок шапки */

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  /* вот этот селектор все перебивал */
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.search-box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background: #2f3640;
  padding: 10px;
}

.search-box:hover>.search-txt {
  width: 240px;
  padding: 0 6px;
}

.search-box:hover>.search-btn {
  background: white;
}

/* Нужно "усилить" селектор */
.header .search-btn {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2f3640;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.search-txt {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <script defer src="http://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header">
      <a class="logo" href="./index.html"> <img src="img/image.png" width="70" /></a>
      <div class="search-box">
        <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="" placeholder="Type to search">
        <a class="search-btn" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="header-right">
        <a class="active" href="#home">Главная</a>
        <a href="#contact">Контакты</a>
        <a href="#about">О нас</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main class="main">

  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Все работает, спасибо огромное и успехов!